# Including non-open access references?

Tags: discussion, references

Usually, in my answers, I try to only quote references that can easily be accessed by everyone online - whether book chapter available online, or papers in open access journals.

However, I can also get access to papers in other journals. I hesitate a bit about including those, as many people asking questions will probably not be able to access them, though. Anyone have thoughts on how best to handle that?

Comment: Hi, I’m pretty sure this is the same question. If I’m mistaken, feel free to [edit] and we can re-open. Thanks!

Comment: @Susan yes, it indeed is *facepalm* I added the "references" tag to it - I would have found it if that had been there

Comment: No problem; we had a lot of questions on Meta in the early days!